# 404 error when running tomcat 8 using intellij (jersey restful web services)

Tags: rest, maven, intellij-idea, http-status-code-404, tomcat8

I am trying to configure my dev environment for a restful web service using Intellij Ultimate 15.04, Jersey, and tomcat 8. The problem is that I am getting a 404 error when I run the program. When I go to the tomcat splash page, I see the default home page, but when I run the program I get the 404. Here is the web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaeehttp://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SewaneeApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.danielevans.sewaneeapp.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>SewaneeApp</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My java class file:

```
package com.danielevans.sewaneeapp;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    public Response getMsg() {

        return Response.status(200).entity("Hello world").build();

    }
}
```

I am also using maven so the pom.xml file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.danielevans.sewaneeapp</groupId>
<artifactId>RestfulFeed</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Server logs when running the program:

```
    /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/bin/catalina.sh run

    [2016-05-27 11:05:26,817] Artifact RestfulFeed:war exploded: Server is 
    not connected. Deploy is not available.

    27-May-2016 23:05:29.378 INFO [main] 
    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        
    Apache Tomcat/8.0.35

    27-May-2016 23:05:29.383 INFO [main] 
    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          
    May 11 2016 21:57:08 UTC

    27-May-2016 23:05:29.384 INFO [main] 
    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         
    8.0.35.0

    27-May-2016 23:05:29.384 INFO [main] 
    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               
    Linux

    27-May-2016 23:05:29.385 INFO [main] 
    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            
    4.2.0-36-generic

    27-May-2016 23:05:29.386 INFO [main] 
    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          
    amd64

    27-May-2016 23:05:29.386 INFO [main] 
    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre

    27-May-2016 23:05:29.387 INFO [main] 
    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           
    1.8.0_91-b14

    27-May-2016 23:05:29.387 INFO [main] 
    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            
    Oracle Corporation

    27-May-2016 23:05:29.388 INFO [main] 
    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         
   /home/danielevans/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed_RestfulFeed

    27-May-2016 23:05:29.388 INFO [main] 
    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         
    /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.35

    27-May-2016 23:05:29.390 INFO [main] 
    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line 
    argument:-                                                 
Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/danielevans/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/syste   m/tomcat/Unnamed_RestfulFeed/conf/logging.properties
   27-May-2016 23:05:29.391 INFO [main]                                
   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line    
   argument: -
   Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   27-May-2016 23:05:29.392 INFO [main]          org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line    argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
   27-May-2016 23:05:29.392 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line    argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
   27-May-2016 23:05:29.393 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line    argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
   27-May-2016 23:05:29.394 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line    argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
   27-May-2016 23:05:29.394 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line    argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
   27-May-2016 23:05:29.395 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line    argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
   27-May-2016 23:05:29.395 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line    argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/endorsed
   27-May-2016 23:05:29.396 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line    argument: -   Dcatalina.base=/home/danielevans/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed   _RestfulFeed
   27-May-2016 23:05:29.397 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line    argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.35
   27-May-2016 23:05:29.397 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line    argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/temp
   27-May-2016 23:05:29.398 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based    Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in    production environments was not found on the java.library.path:    /usr/local/idea-IU-   145.972.3/bin::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/li   b
   27-May-2016 23:05:30.560 INFO [main]    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler    ["http-nio-8080"]
   27-May-2016 23:05:30.664 INFO [main]    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a    shared selector for servlet write/read
   27-May-2016 23:05:30.677 INFO [main]    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler    ["ajp-nio-8009"]
   27-May-2016 23:05:30.681 INFO [main]    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a    shared selector for servlet write/read
   27-May-2016 23:05:30.683 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 3098    ms
   27-May-2016 23:05:30.792 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service    Catalina
   27-May-2016 23:05:30.793 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet    Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.35
   27-May-2016 23:05:30.850 INFO [main]    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-   nio-8080"]
   27-May-2016 23:05:30.917 INFO [main]    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-   nio-8009"]
   27-May-2016 23:05:30.932 INFO [main]    org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 248 ms
   Connected to server
   [2016-05-27 11:05:31,321] Artifact RestfulFeed:war exploded: Artifact    is being deployed, please wait...
   27-May-2016 23:05:34.723 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1]    org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned    for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a    complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them.    Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP    compilation time.
   [2016-05-27 11:05:35,011] Artifact RestfulFeed:war exploded: Artifact    is deployed successfully
   [2016-05-27 11:05:35,012] Artifact RestfulFeed:war exploded: Deploy    took 3,691 milliseconds
   27-May-2016 23:05:40.961 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]    org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web    application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/manager
   27-May-2016 23:05:41.238 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]    org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web    application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/manager has    finished in 275 ms
```

Just saw these, the tomcat LocalHost Log:

```
27-May-2016 23:38:50.735 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Marking servlet SewaneeApp as unavailable
27-May-2016 23:38:50.739 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet SewaneeApp
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.danielevans.sewaneeapp.HelloWorld cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Solved: Okay so after all of these edits, I have figured out what was wrong. The hint was the last edit containing the tomcat localhost logs, which said there was a  ClassCastException (have to thank Emad for essentially telling me to look at the logs closer) to javax.servlet.Servlet.

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.danielevans.sewaneeapp.HelloWorld cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
```

To fix this, I replaced this

```
<servlet-class>com.danielevans.sewaneeapp.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
```

with this:

```
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

The short explanation for this is that the `<servlet-class>` ... `</servlet-class>` element defines the servlet that will handle the request, so specifying the helloworld (see code above) class did not make sense there, which resulted in the 404 error.

The longer explanation (with some extra info for free ;) ) is that the web.xml file defines a mapping between the URL paths and the servlets that handle requests with those paths. The web server uses this configuration to identify the servlet to handle a given request and call the class method that corresponds to the request method. The `<servlet>` element declares the servlet, including a name used to refer to the servlet by other elements in the file

The `<servlet-mapping>` element specifies a URL pattern and the name of a declared servlet to use for requests whose URL matches the pattern.

To learn more about the web.xml file, go to this link: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#JSPs

Comment: can you show us the Log?

Comment: @Emad I added the server logs

Comment: Hey have  you solved it?